# React - Filter Multidimensional array with another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return only matches results.

My array:

```
products: [
 {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Product 1",
 "concepts": [
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Blabla"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Zlazla"
  }
 ]
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
 "name": "Product 2",
 "concepts": [
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Gulagula"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Zlazla"
  }
 ]
 }
]
```

I want to filter products which only have one of the concepts below.

concepts array:

```
['14', '15']
```

Couldn't solve this in an easy way.

Comment: please add the code you have tried

Comment: `products.filter(v => v.concepts.every(a => ['14', '15'].includes(a)))`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly, change `every` to `some` and you're looking for `[14,15]` to include `a.id`

Comment: You can add this filter statement : 
products.filter(x => x.concepts.every(a => [14,15].includes(a.id)));

Comment: _filter products which only have one of the concepts_ <-- this is not clear. The `concepts` array is `['14', '15']`. If you need to filter products which **ONLY have ONE** of the concepts, then you need to output `Product 1` because it has only ONE (ie, `'15'`). I don't think that is what you expect. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```js
var products=  [
 {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Product 1",
 "concepts": [
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Blabla"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Zlazla"
  }
 ]
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
 "name": "Product 2",
 "concepts": [
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Gulagula"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Zlazla"
  }
 ]
 }
]    

var products = products.filter((product) => product.concepts = product.concepts.filter( (x) => x.id == 14 || x.id == 15));
    
console.log(products);
```